# I'm getting AttributeError when I call a method in other class

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I have a code like this:

```
class Configuration:
 @staticmethod
 def test():
    return "Hello World"
```

When I call the method `test` from other python code like this:

```
import test

test.Configuration.test()
```

I get an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    test.Configuration.test()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'
```

where I'm making the mistake?

### Edit:

My directory structure:

```
root
--example.py
--test
----__init.py__
----Configuration.py
```

Comment: Do you have a *directory* `test` with a file `Configuration.py` in it somewhere? Or did you have a file `Configuration.py` that you imported in `test`?

Comment: What does `import test; print test.Configuration.__file__` print?

Comment: If you mean another python file by saying another python code, you should create an empty `__init__.py` in same directory with your test function located.

Comment: @ali: The OP is not trying to create a package here. That is *not* the problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Its printing the `Configuration` location.. like `/dir/Configuration.pyc`.

Comment: Perhaps its your indentation of the `test` method.

Comment: @batman: Clearly not your `Configuration` class. And `print test.__file__` prints?

Comment: @segfolt: Nope. Yes the indentation in the post here is wrong but that is not the cause of the error here. Clearly what is imported is not what is expected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It prints `__init__.pyc` location..

Comment: @batman: You are importing a `test` **package**, not `test.py`. You have more files kicking around here than you posted about. Remove the `test` package (directory) or rename it, then test again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have edited my question. `example.py` is where I'm trying to call `Configuration.test()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Out of curiosity: How are you sure it's an importation problem?

Comment: @segfolt: Yes, see the responses from the OP to my queries for `print` output.

Comment: @batman: Right. What wasn't clear is that you defined a class with th e same name as the file it is in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You mean thats wrong?!!! I'm completely struck here!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python module names and the classes they contain are *separate*. You need use the full path:

```
import test

print test.Configuration.Configuration.test()
```

Your `test` package has a module named `Configuration`, and *inside* that module is your `Configuration` class.

Note that Python, unlike Java, lets you define methods outside classes too, no need to make this a static method.  Nor do you need to use a separate file per class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your module to something other than 'test', since this is the name of a standard library module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html) and probably you're importing that module instead of your own. Another option is to add the directory containing your test module into the PYTHONPATH environment variable, so that python may find it instead of the standard library module (but this is not advised as it shadows the standard module and you won't be able to import it later).

To check which file you're importing from, do:

```
import test
print test
```

Comment: There is no `Configuration` file in the python `test` package. There is no `Configuration.py` file *anywhere* in the Python library.